# What is the difference between 'set ft=' and 'setfiletype'?

Tags: filetype

I am using vim 8.1. When I need to change the default filetype for `.s` extension to `gas` (which by default is `asm`), I first look for the default command to set filetype in `/usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim`. It contains [this line](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.1.0022/runtime/filetype.vim#L157):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.asm,*.[sS],*.[aA],*.mac,*.lst   call dist#ft#FTasm()
```

Then, I tried to overwrite that in my `vimrc` with this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.s setfiletype gas
```

But, it doesn't work. Filetype still `asm` when I open any `*.s` file.

Then, when I use this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.s set ft=gas
```

It works.

So, what is the difference between `set ft=<filetype>` and `setfiletype <filetype>`?

Comment: note that `setfiletype=gas` is not even a valid syntax, it would be `setfiletype gas`

Comment: yeah, definitely not valid XD

Comment: @Mass Just edited the question to fix that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the `:setfiletype` help:

```
:setf[iletype] [FALLBACK] {filetype}                    :setf :setfiletype
                     Set the 'filetype' option to {filetype}, but only if
                     not done yet in a sequence of (nested) autocommands.
                     This is short for:
                             :if !did_filetype()
                             :  setlocal filetype={filetype}
                             :endif
                     This command is used in a filetype.vim file to avoid
                     setting the 'filetype' option twice, causing different
                     settings and syntax files to be loaded.

                     When the optional FALLBACK argument is present, a
                     later :setfiletype command will override the
                     'filetype'.  This is to used for filetype detections
                     that are just a guess.  did_filetype() will return
                     false after this command.
```

So `:setfiletype` does not override existing file type, when `:set ft` does.